# How to achieve a background image continuous move in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a background image in my wpf application, I want to achieve a effect of the background image continuous move. The following code can achieve a simple effect, but when the time of the end of the picture moves over again, I want to make this picture the effect of the movement has been the phenomenon does not come to a halt.

```
void StartBackgroudMove()
{
    Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
    DoubleAnimation TranslateXExtendAnimation = new DoubleAnimation() { From = 0, To = -100, Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2500) };
    Storyboard.SetTarget(TranslateXExtendAnimation, BackgroundImage);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(TranslateXExtendAnimation, new PropertyPath("(FrameworkElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)"));
    sb.Children.Add(TranslateXExtendAnimation);
    sb.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop;
    sb.Completed += (s, args) =>
    {
        this.StartBackgroudMove();
    };
    sb.Begin();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use an ImageBrush with `TileMode` set to `Tile` and animate its `Viewport` property:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg"
                    Stretch="Fill" TileMode="Tile"
                    ViewportUnits="Absolute" Viewport="0,0,1024,768"/>
    </Grid.Background>
    <Grid.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <RectAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Viewport"
                                   To="-1024,0,1024,768" Duration="0:0:10" 
                                   RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Grid.Triggers>
</Grid>
```

The following alternative solution places two adjacent images in a Canvas and animates the Canvas' `RenderTransform` property.

```
<Grid>
    <Canvas>
        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform x:Name="translation"/>
        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
        <Image Stretch="None"
               Source="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg"/>
        <Image Canvas.Left="1024" Stretch="None"
               Source="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg"/>
    </Canvas>
    <Grid.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" 
                                     Storyboard.TargetName="translation"
                                     To="-1024" Duration="0:0:10"
                                     RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Grid.Triggers>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I would also like to ask a question： If it's just a Image not a ImageBrush, how to achieve the effect?

Comment: You may use two Image controls displaying the same image, perhaps in a common container like a StackPanel. Then move both (or the container) by one image width before reverting to the initial position. If you're getting problems with the implementation I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: I have try according what you mean. I found I could't make the two picture move one by one smoothy.

Comment: Hi Clemens, yours is a very good customizable snippet. Works like a charm. However, I plugged in a different set of values suiting to my needs. Made the viewport match my grid's size and used a FlipX TileMode.
Also, I have edited your answer. Changed the RoutedEvent from "Loaded" to "Grid.Loaded" sine Loaded isn't recognized as a RoutedEvent.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `Storyboard.RepeatBehavior` to `RepeatBehavior.Forever`

Example:

```
    void StartBackgroudMove()
    {
        Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
        DoubleAnimation TranslateXExtendAnimation = new DoubleAnimation() { From = 0, To = -100, Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2500) };
        Storyboard.SetTarget(TranslateXExtendAnimation, BackgroundImage);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(TranslateXExtendAnimation, new PropertyPath("(FrameworkElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)"));
        sb.Children.Add(TranslateXExtendAnimation);
        sb.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop;
        sb.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
        sb.Begin();
    }
```

Comment: The effect of the background image continuous move can be achieved, but there still has the halt phenomenon. When the picture moved 100, it moved again from scratch. I want it to be continuous move without a halt. Can you do it?